# Create Bootable USB in elementary OS

Tags: usb

I'm trying to upgrade to Freya from Luna and I need to create a bootable usb drive.

Ubuntu has Startup Disk Creator, what does elementary OS have?

Comment: I tried to install by appcenter and by terminal by I can't. I see in the application the icon but when I try to start the appliccation I recieved this
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMOav.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMOav.jpg) And when i try to install by appcenter I see this [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6RZf.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6RZf.jpg) I don't know how to fix the problem!
For example I have the same problem for install Wine too.

Answer (score 14):

You have Startup Disk Creator as in Ubuntu you can install it from the AppCenter or via the command line:

```
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

Answer (score 5):

Use AppCentre to install the "Disks" application, it will do the job and is useful for other things too. Start it, carefully select the USB drive from the list on the left, then use the menu top right to select "Restore Disk Image" and choose your iso file. It works fine on Ubuntu MATE, but I haven't tried it on ElementaryOS.

Answer (score 1):

Since elementary is derivative of ubuntu , start up disk creator would work just fine , or you can use unetbootin as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Image Burner](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.artemanufrij.imageburner.desktop) in the App Center or [Etcher](https://etcher.io/). Both are easy to use and reliable.

[image]